# How to manage magento CSS file with over 10,000 lines?

Tags: css, magento

I'm a beginner with Magento, but I've been handed a css file with over 10,000 lines. The site has had a few developers work on it before I came along (I'm new), so I'm not exactly sure what is custom and what's part of the theme. There are no comments, and there seems to be some sort of grid-based css framework as well as normalizer.css

This is a typical e-commerce site with a shopping cart, check out steps, etc.
Is 10,000+ lines of css overkill? I really don't know where to begin.

Also, I noticed a lot of classes have their own rules that is essentially a mini-clearfix.
for example:

```
.first-item:after, first-item:before {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.first-item:after {
    clear: both;
}
.second-item:after, first-item:before {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.second-item:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Is this necessary? Why not just throw clear-fix classes onto those elements, or at least combine those rules into:

```
for example:
first-item:before, first-item:after,
second-item:before, second-item: after, {
    ....
}
```

I'm kind of in a situation where I don't know what I don't know, so if you guys could let me know whether the file is overkill, or I just don't know enough of what I'm doing.

Comment: Convert, rewrite to LESS (or something like) then separate by logical sections. (sample in bootstrap)

Comment: There should be no reason on earth to have 10K lines of CSS for any page.

Comment: 10K is about average for a standard uncompressed Magento style file.  If you have to keep in mind that the file contains styles for every single piece of core frontend functionality in Magento, so it's not going to be small.

Comment: Furthermore, the size of the file should never be an issue when it comes to editing it.  Use the tools you have available.  Browser developer tools such as Firebug will tell you the exact css file and line the definition for an element is on.  Then you simply jump to that line using your code editor and make the change.  Use the searching tools available in your editing software to jump around the file quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone.
I use Firebug to target specific elements I want to affect, but because the content is generated by Magento, some of the styles on a single element may be affected (I don't mean inherited) by an ancestor nth-removed.

Jumping around on a stylesheet also sounds less efficient than I had expected. But if that's the best way to go about it, I have no problem accepting that fact...

Comment: Understanding what class names are assigned to what frontend elements just comes with experience with working with any pre-built system such as Magento.  Magento follows a pretty standard class naming convention so you can kind of guess what each class is used for.

Comment: @j08691 - in the Pre-Web App world, this would be a valid assessment. Magento has gone far beyond that with classes and IDs for a very complex user interface that can be custom tailored. It's for **ALL** the pages that Magento displays. Not much is left to chance. As someone put it, Magento was written by programmers, for programmers to provide programmers with work.

Comment: That is to say: I should target what I need, write rules to override and customize? For you front end developers, what's your day-to-day like? Is your workflow constantly inspecting elements to identify specific ones, and then writing rules and styles to them?

Comment: Google Chrome's Developer function allows you to inspect elements and change CSS on the fly to see what adjustments are needed. You can then go make the changes to the CSS files after finding out what you like.

Comment: I see. I've been using Firebug and Chrome's developer tool to target things. That I understand how to do. I guess I'm just surprised that this is the way to go about it. It just seems awfully inefficient. Of course, I'm sure it's partly to do with my inexperience with large files.

Comment: @axel You're 100% correct, found this thread as my current Magento-2 project css is around 10k and we couldn't make it small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One tool to help cleanup massive CSS files is discussed [here](http://24ways.org/2013/untangling-web-typography/)
In the context of typography. The tools used give a good format for identifying and eliminating other CSS cruft.